# VirtualBox installs, reboots then freezes

Tags: windows, virtualbox, login, crash

I have tried installing 15.04 and 14.04.03 LTS on multiple computers and revisions of VirtualBox, both of which have given the same error.

When I try to install Ubuntu in VirtualBox, it installs fine. But after I install and I get asked to restart after installation (to boot from hard drive), following that I receive the *log in to the accounts*, (one being the one i created, and a Guest Session).

I log in to the account I created, using the password I created. After the log in, I get stuck on the wallpaper screen, (as usual to log in to the account, and get to the desktop), I get gray lines on screen, for about a second, then I get brought back to the log in screen, (for entering the password).

This happens every time.

I have tried using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and tried logging in and it works, but I am only on a command terminal, not on a desktop

Settings (these are the amd a8 settings, these are the settings for all the computers, including the test)

Settings

[image: Setting one]

[image: Setting two]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30380/discussion-on-question-by-naturalistubuntu-virtualbox-installs-reboots-then-fre).